# How to do query for two different association DFS tables?

Tags: sql, dolphindb, distributed-database

How to do query for two different association DFS tables?
Does DolphinDB have restrictions on queries of the association DFS tables?

Answer (score 0):

(1) The table association of the DFS table needs to be under the same database database

(2) If two large DFS tables need to be associated, they should have the same partition scheme and be saved in the same database.

(3) If a small table is associated with a large DFS table, the small table can be stored in the same database as a dimension table.

(4) For in-memory tables, The queries of associated tables do not have the above restrictions.